# What level of enchantment gives me the best chance for Aqua Affinity or Respiration?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

As I understand it, dumping 30 levels into a Diamond Helmet actually gives me a non-optimal chance to get *Aqua Affinity* or *Respiration* specifically. Assuming I'm not mistaken, what level of enchantment should I be applying to maximize my chances of receiving these specific enchantments?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually, you are mistaken. I have run 1 million enchantments for each level from 1 to 30 and counted the number of times I got each particular enchantment. Here are the results for diamond helmet:
[image: diamond helmet]

You can clearly see that 30 level enchanting gives the maximum chance of getting Respiration or Aqua Affinity.

Running the same test for a golden helmet (which has better enchantability) gives almost the same picture - Aqua affinity actually peaks on level 28, but Respiration III is rising significantly on levels 29 and 30, so still a better strategy is to enchant on level 30:
[image: golden helmet]

[Here is the raw data](http://pastebin.com/Gs3kATBN) including all diamond helmet enchantments if you'd like to play around with it. I have used MCP 9.03 (Minecraft 1.7.2) to generate the results, but I'm not aware of any changes in the enchantment probabilities since then. Even in the upcoming 1.8 where the enchanting mechanic is changed, the probabilities and enchantment selection were not changed (according to Jeb). It is possible however that the enchanting will be revisited once more before the final 1.8 release.

I guess I could include the [book enchantment probabilities](http://pastebin.com/BCqqabDg) for completeness, but they are lower than the helmet ones by an order of magnitude:
[image: book]

Comment: Holy SCIENCE batman!

Comment: So you spent weeks on running the same enchantment over and over again? Quite unlikely you did.

Comment: @poepje I didn't do this manually, I used [Mod Coder Pack](http://mcp.ocean-labs.de/) to decompile the game and wrote a Java program that invokes the enchanting code. The method I used is mentioned in the answer. But the thought of me sitting in front of stacks of anvils, filling tens of thousands of double chests of helmets and then counting the enchantments made me giggle, so thanks :)

Comment: @Kcats Oh sorry, I didn't know that was possible. While I'm at it though, I still don't understand how this works completely. I've tried to enchant a bunch of different armors and weapons at and around lvl30, yet I ALWAYS get the exact same basic enchantments. As for (iron/gold) helmets, not once did I get anything different than protection I and blast protection I. Do you know how this can happen?

Comment: @poepje It is pretty much impossible to get Protection I on level 30. If you are getting Protection I and Blast Protection I, you are probably doing a low level enchanting. Are you sure you are pressing the button for level 30 (the lowest of the three) and that you have the required 15 bookshelves?

Comment: @Kcats Ehh no, I don't have bookshelves and honestly didn't know they were required... I then assume you ran the tests with bookshelves?

Answer (score -2):

Well I'm not to sure, but you could try enchanting a book to level 30. As far as I know books are much more enchantable than armour. Or you could just enchant a gold helmet which is more enchantable than books.

Hope it helps...

P.S. You also might want to check on the Minecraft Forums.

Comment: More "Enchantable"?

Comment: @peper757 The item material has effect on the enchantment probabilities, gold being the 'most enchantable' material